# How long would it take the air conditioner to exchange the air in your room that is 11ft by 12ft by 8.5ft?

Tags: volume, chemistry

I have this question in chemistry. It's really just for getting you use to conversions.

Here's the question: You have a bedroom that is 11ft wide by 12ft long by 8.5ft high and has an air conditioner that exchanges 1200L air per minute. How long would it take the air conditioner to exchange the air in your room once?

Here's what I have done so far: Convert from English to Metric,

$$11ft*({12in\over1ft})*({2.54cm\over1})*({1m\over100cm}) = 3.3528m$$

$$12ft*({12in\over1ft})*({2.54cm\over1})*({1m\over100cm}) = 3.6576m$$

$$8.5ft*({12in\over1ft})*({2.54cm\over1})*({1m\over100cm}) = 2.5908m$$

Note: I'm supposed to take the number of significant figures into account.

It may have been easier to convert the $1200L$ instead.

So the volume of the room: $$3.3528m*3.6576m*2.5908m=31.77250188m^3$$
Convert that to L: $$31.77250188m^3*{1L\over 1000m^3}=0.0317725019L$$
So, the volume of the room is $0.0317725019L$ and the air is being exchanged at $1200L$ air per minute. How long will it take for the air to be exchanged once? This is where I've stuck, any help? Or hints?
Thank you!

Comment: A liter is about the volume of a grapefruit, or a nice glass of beer.  Your room is larger than that: it has more then .03 L in it.  I think your mistake is in thinking that $1L/(1000m^3) = 1$.  A liter has 1000 cubic cm; a cubic m has 1000 L.

Comment: @Peter I still can't figure out the volume. is it: $$31.77250188m^3 * {1L\over 1000cm^3}$$?

Comment: No, it is $31.7725\cdot 1000L=31772.5L$

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. Do you have any resources for problems like this? I'm really bad at them and need some more practice. I have tried googling but I can't find any that have answers so I can check myself.

Comment: Of course, in reality probably there will be molecules that never get exchanged, possibly exponential decay would be a reasonable model (depending on the rate of convection, etc.).

Comment: one you are missing a cancelling of units in the conversion to cubic metres and a wrong one for conversion to litres.

Comment: Some air molecules may be trapped (e.g. inside sealed containers), and these will never be exchanged unless the containers are opened (or they quantum-mechanically tunnel through the container).

Answer (score 0):

The air conditioner needs $$\frac{31.7725\cdot 1000L}{1200\frac{L}{\min}}=26.477\min$$

that is about $26$ minutes and $29$ seconds.

Comment: Would it just be $$0.0317725019L * {1\over 1200} * {L\over min}$$? I'm pretty sure something is wrong here.